# Keeping shirts crease free when commuting

Tags: commuter, clothes

I'm a manager in an office and need to wear shirt and tie every day.  I am also a keen commuter cyclist (5 mi cycle to station, train, 0.5 mi walk to office).

I've tried panniers, rucksack, rolling shirts up, trying to keep flat and folded...but as yet I still end up with more creases than I'd like.

Any advice on how to keep my shirts as crease free as possible? 
 *(Oddly enough, my trousers always seem to come out nicely!)*

Comment: I would call mom and ask which material is more resistant to wrinkles. She will know ;)

Comment: Seems more appropriate to the Travel board.

Comment: Consider changing the dress code at work to something more cycle friendly.  You are the manager!  You have the power!

Comment: Can you keep an iron and ironing board at work?  How about have a couple of sports jackets at work to wear over the shirts on alternate days until your body heat warms them and irons them from the inside-out?

Comment: Can you store your working cloth at work, so it will suffer from just one ride, bout not 5/week?

Comment: Is there a dry cleaners or laundry that would do a service wash near your office? That way, you won't need to carry your shirts to and fro

Comment: I do tailoring and I can tell you that nothing will be perfect. Make sure your shirt fits properly and perhaps try some wrinkle resistant fabrics like Lyocell, Polyester, Cashmere blends or some other fabric.